# Need cron 'type' approach that runs constantly

Tags: php, apache, cron

I need a decent approach to helping run a cron type script on my shared hosting server. For now - it will have to stay a share hosting account, so that doesn't change. And I understand that a "cron" can do this and set the intervals to be every minute. But I would like to see if we could get it a little faster than that.

I've created a web based application that loops over directories and files within those directories. When a new file is found, it then executes the rest of the stuff that needs to happen. This all works as it should and nothing is needed there. These files that are being processed are files of 'urgency'. They help local departments and people actually respond to these files when they are processed. So the 'urgency' factor is important in here.

With that being said, it would be interesting to hear the best approach to execute this script on a frequent basis, (like every 30 seconds or so) without:

1. Having the hosting company step in
2. Eating up too many resources (memory/queries, etc. There's minimal queries happening)
3. Still allowing this task to be completed regularly without issues.

As a side note: I do have access to multiple accounts on multiple servers and one way I thought about was to creating individual files on those accounts to run as well, and just do something like `file_get_contents` (even though no output happens) so it would execute the script. Again - the "urgency" is a huge factor in this application so it's important to make this run as fast as possible, but at least allowing for a file to be 'archived' and a couple of queries to run - without overstepping each other in the process (duplications)

I do have access to CLI (shell) if that helps as well.

Comment: you may want to look into `watch` http://beerpla.net/2007/08/04/watch-a-useful-linux-command-you-may-have-never-heard-of/

Answer (score 1):

One super simple option - Have the cron run the task every minute:

```
function task()
{
    doYourThing();
    sleep(30);
    doYourThing();
}
```

Its not ideal - but it technically runs the doYourThing() every 30seconds.

Edit: why dont you 'trigger' an event when people upload new files to run the task on demand?

Comment: I've thought about triggering some event when they upload. The thing is, they upload via a standard windows .bat file. And without having them install something extra on their computer, or having a browser open everytime something is uploaded, I don't know of a way in the bat process to trigger something. Suggestions?

Comment: How does the bat file on windows upload to your server? Can the bat file 'hit' a url on your website - which triggers the task?

Comment: it uses an ftp command in the bat file. Yes the bat file could hit a url on the server, but from my understanding, only by opening a browser, unless the user installs something like curl on their machines. I really don't want to complicate this for them. Unless I am missing something that can be used in bat files...